how can we access the content of mounted blob storage to webapp through webapp url
I have mounted a blob storage to a webapp. When I ssh into webapp it shows me directory of that container and inside that directory I can see files that I have uploaded in the blob storage but I want to access those files using webapp URL

in the above image shown that where and how i have mounted blob storage to webapp
I am trying to access content of mounted blob storag to webapp using webapp URL
for example :
https://.azurewebsites.net//
container-name we can find from /home/site/wwwroot/container-name it can be same or can be different depending upon what we have put in mount path

What is the framework of your WebApp?

i am using node but i haven't deployed my code in it and why does framework matter in this case

So,you have just uploaded blob and trying to access it ?

AFAIK,the files uploaded by blob or any static files in the site/wwwroot folder cannot be accessed directly from web app.You need to give access it from code to server the files.

Iam able to access the Fiels, will post an answer in detail.

Are you still facing the issue?

No, I didn't try this solution yet(I don't have code side access so I am not able to try this).Found the alternate way

Can you please share the alternative sol.

I just wanted to access the content of storage container without making it public so go on Storage account > Static Website (From side menu ) and Enabled the option so it will create one container called $web inside our storage account and whichever file I upload in that container I can access it throuh the url

To serve the static or any files which are uploaded from blob, you need to define the route in the app.js file.

Refer this MSdoc to create and deploy Node App to Azure App Service.

Your app.js  by default serves the root directory


var  indexRouter  =  require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', indexRouter);


You need to add the route to access the container/any specific folder.

You can refer the similar thread which I have addressed for ASP.Net CORE App.

Add the below line of code in app.js file.


app.use('/containername', express.static('/home/site/wwwroot/containername'));

Mount Storage:

Folder deployed from Mount storage:

Output:

